# How to install certain node version from command line

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to install node 6.9.4.

In windows console I try with this:

```
npm install node@v6.9.4
```

And it throws this error:

```
npm ERR! No compatible version found: node@v6.9.4
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! 0.0.0
```

In linux the result is similar. I try with

```
sudo npm install node@v6.9.4
```

and the output is:

```
npm ERR! version not found: node@6.9.4-cls
```

Is there a way to install certain node version with npm?

Comment: Can you update your npm with `npm install -g npm` and then try to install node again?

Comment: You cannot install node via npm. 
NPM is the package manager for node.

Inorder to install a particular version of node. You can use nvm

Comment: Also you should avoid installing packaged with sudo

Comment: Many thanks, Sahan, but the result is the same, as if there where no node versions, just 0.0.0

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should use [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install and manage node versions and not `npm`

[NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/) is the package manager for node and not a version manager.

To install a particular version of node using nvm, just do

`nvm install v0.10.32`

NPM should be used to install packages/modules.
So say you need to use request module for a particular project
You can do

`npm install request`

Both these support tons of options which could be found over the documentations

Answer (score 10):

I recommend you use [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm): Nodev Version Manager

It would be as easy as

```
nvm install 6.9.4
```

It's a really good tool to manager all of your node versions.

Comment: **This is not the package you are looking for: please go to http://nvm.sh**
It throws this error

Answer (score 0):

Since I found this when searching how to update nodejs, I thought I'd drop this here:

```
npm install nodejs@14
```